# virtumart 1.1.5 i need paypal pro method .there is any opton for configure paypal pro method?

Tags: php, joomla, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

In virtumart 1.1.5 i need paypal pro payment method .there is any option for configure PayPal pro payment method?and what pay pal sandbox details needed PayPal pro payment method.

Comment: This request may be best suited in the product's support forums.

Comment: thank you. can you  please provide me the link for same.

Comment: Problem with the VM forum is that no one cares to answer your questions. It's *mostly* a bunch of selfish people that just want to make money on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of what needs to be changed, the only main difference between Paypal Pro and Standard is that you need to post to a different URL (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/acquiringweb) and the format of the posted querystring is slightly different.

If you can find this in the VM code, you could change it there as the payment process is the same for both.